# why is minimal ts-vue template not working?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

```
<template>
  <div>{{ keyword }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

export default class Page extends Vue {
  private keyword = ''
}
</script>
```

get error:

> Property or method "keyword" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the `@Component` decorator.

```
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class Page extends Vue {
  private keyword = ''
}
```

Comment: bingo. but other component doesn't have the @Component decorator, and still working, why's that?

Comment: Because they're not `class`, just plain object. Too much context missing, hard to go deeper, you need to learn more about vue and js basics.